# Can not add active class to nav elements, with nav being imported from another .html file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This is my first leap on trying to implement a HTML/CSS website, so please take this into consideration.

I have multiple .html pages that implement the navbar from a nav.html, using a jQuery function( i guess?). The other html's are similar to index.
Any idea of what's wrong?

```
    <script>
     $(function(){
       $("#nav-placeholder").load("nav.html");
        });
    </script>
```

The code i used for adding active class is pure JS.
Here is index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9a39db93cf.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script>
            let count = 0;
            function counter()
            {
                count++;
                document.querySelector('#pageContent').innerHTML = count;
            }
        </script>    
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $("#nav-placeholder").load("nav.html");
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            const currentLocation = location.href;
            const menuItem = document.querySelectorAll('a');
            const menuLength = menuItem.length
            for( let i=0; i<menuLength; i++){
                if(menuItem[i].href === currentLocation){
                    menuItem[i].className = "active";
                }
            }
        </script>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>My Webpage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="nav-placeholder" class="sticky-top">

        </div>
        <div class="firstPage">
            <h4>The title of this paragraph</h4>
            <img onclick="counter(); return false;" src="images/mirciun.jpg" alt="mirciun" height=auto max-width=auto class="center">
            <p id='pageContent'>0</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}

.menu li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.topnav{
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align:center;
    overflow: hidden;

}

ul.topnav li a{
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: whitesmoke;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.topnav li a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #222;}
ul.topnav li a.active {background-color: #4CAF50;}

@media screen and (max-width: "600px") { 
    ul.topnav li {float: none;}
  }

#brand{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height:50px;
}

#topText{
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 5px solid green;
    color: red;
    background-color: #0f0f0f;
    margin-top: 10px;

}
.firstPage
{
    margin-top: -20px;
    background-color:grey;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

h4{
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;

}
.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

#pageContent{
    text-align:center;
    width: 75%;
    margin: auto;
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: what is going wrong? i don't see a problem description only "what is wrong", are you getting console errors? is anything unexpected happening?

Comment: wrap your javscript code `const currentLocation = location.href;
            const menuItem = document.querySelectorAll('a');
            const menuLength = menuItem.length
            for( let i=0; i<menuLength; i++){
                if(menuItem[i].href === currentLocation){
                    menuItem[i].className = "active";
                }
            }` with `$(function() {})` and move that javascript tag to the bottom of the body tag.

Comment: You are adding the active class before content was loaded. The jQuery `$(function(){ ... })` executes after DOM load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, i solved it using `$( window ).on( "load", function(){`, instead of  `$( document ).ready(function () {` . The short explanation is that code will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready. - > https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0):

wrap your code with jquery on ready function and move to the bottom of the page.

```
$(function () {
const currentLocation = location.href;
const menuItem = document.querySelectorAll('a');
const menuLength = menuItem.length
for (let i = 0; i < menuLength; i++) {
    if (menuItem[i].href === currentLocation) {
        menuItem[i].className = "active";
    }
}
```

})

Comment: I have added this just before </body> tag :
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                const currentLocation = location.href;
                const menuItem = document.querySelectorAll('a');
                const menuLength = menuItem.length
                for (let i = 0; i < menuLength; i++) {
                    if (menuItem[i].href === currentLocation) {
                        menuItem[i].className = "active";
                    }
                }
                })
            </script>
Still not working.